# BigQuery "This query will process 0 B when run"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery and wondering why it gives different process amounts when running codes as shown below.

- case1

  - code:
    `` SELECT count(*) FROM `table ``
  - result:
    "This query will process 0 GB when run."
- case2

  - code:
    `` SELECT * FROM `table ``
  - result:
    "This query will process 4.72 GB when run."

I think BQ charges for the amounts it scans for each query. Is scanning amounts different betewen these two cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case 1 - BigQuery does not scan actual data at all and rather uses [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#us_and_eu_multi-region_locations) to just simply get count of rows - that's why [it is free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#samplecosts).